# Mat Select displaying empty options with Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs-observables

I am creating mat-select options using results from Observable but the options are not rendering. When it simple array it is rendering.

Following is the example i build - [See here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-xznxzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using `from` observable. Instead use `of` observable, it will convert your simple array to observable that will work with `async pipe`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toppingList = of(['a', 'b']);
  }
```

Difference between `of` and `from` when passing an array-like structure (including strings):

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

would print the whole array at once.

On the other hand,

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

prints the elements 1 by 1.

For strings the behaviour is the same, but at character level.